# Virtualized web server structure

Tags: networking, virtualization, domain

I am on the process to virtulize (proxmox) my physical server and I successfully created several environments like lunix VMs, LXC containers and other Windows VM too. Most VMs and Containers are web servers and should be accesed through outside of local network. I need to point respective domains to them.

My question is how to forward respective domain into VMs and LXC containers? I have internal IPs and I can create one centralized VM which will get all traffic to apache2 and forward it by proxy into VMs but is this correct way, is there are any better practice? I need proper structure within server for to not get stuck in future.

King Regards.